# Is there a name for the irregular spelling difference between some nouns and verbs?

Tags: terminology, orthography, parts-of-speech

Most words that have a noun-form and a verb-form (noun/verb pairs) have identical spelling, e.g. *a jump* (n.), *to jump* (v.).

However, some words have different spelling:

> *advi**c**e* (n.), *advi**s**e* (v.)
>
> *licen**c**e* (n.), *licen**s**e* (v.)
>
> ***e**ffect* (n.), ***a**ffect* (v.)
>
> *li**f**e* (n.), *li**v**e* (v.)
>
> *sa**f**e* (adj.), *sa**v**e* (v.)
>
> *belie**f*** (n.), *belie**ve*** (v.)

Is there a general name for these minor spelling differences for related words? It's not *conjugation* because that only applies to verbs. I'm looking for a word that means *conjugation*, but between nouns and verbs, adjectives and verbs, etc.

---

#### EDIT

There are a couple of comments saying that *effect* and *affect* have different meanings. I included them to show that my question is not just about the difference between the unvoiced (n.) and voiced (v.) spellings of the words. If anyone can think of a better example to include in my question I'd appreciate it.

However, consulting my Macquarie Dictionary, it gives the following definitions:

> **effect** /əˈfɛkt, i-/, *n.* **1.** that which is produced by some agency or cause; a result; a consequence: *the effect of heat.* **2.** power to produce results; efficacy; force; validity; weight: *of no effect.* **3.** the state of being operative; operation or execution; accomplishment or fulfilment: *to bring a plan into effect.* **4.** a mental impression produced, as by a painting, speech, etc. **5.** the result intended; purport or intent; tenor or significance: *he wrote to that effect.* **6.** (of stage properties) a sight, sound or, occasionally, smell simulated by artificial means to give a particular impression in a theatre. **7.** a scientific phenomenon: *the Doppler effect.* **8.** (*pl.*) goods; movables; personal property. **9. for effect,** for the sake of a desired impression; with histrionic intent. **10. in effect, a.** in fact or reality. **b.** in operation, as a law. **11. take effect,** to operate or begin to operate. *-v.t.* **12.** to produce as an effect; bring about; accomplish; make happen. **13.** to produce or make. [ME, from L *effectus* from *efficere* bring about] **-effecter,** *n.* **-effectible,** *adj.*

---

> **affect¹** /əˈfɛkt/, *v.t.* **1.** to act on; produce an effect or a change in: *cold affects the body.* **2.** to impress; move (in mind or feelings): *the poetry affected me deeply.* **3.** (of pain, disease, etc.) to attack or lay hold of. *-n.* **4.** *Psychol.* feeling or emotion. **5.** *Obs.* affection; passion; sensation; inclination; inward disposition or feeling. [L *affectus*, pp., influenced, attacked]
>
> **affect²** /əˈfɛkt/, *v.t.* **1.** to make a show of; put on a pretence of; pretend; feign: *to affect ignorance.* **2.** [...]

To me, definitions **1.** and **5.** of **effect** look like the same meaning as definitions **1.** and **2.** of **affect¹**.

*The effect of heat is different for everyone.* (effect, def. 1.)

*Heat affects everyone differently.* (affect¹, def. 1.)

**Heat effects everyone differently.* (effect, def. 12. or 13.)

**affect²** is a completely different meaning about pretending and other meanings, which is why I haven't included the full text.

I am aware that the etymology shows different meanings, but the modern English meanings don't match the Latin meanings anyway. It's even possible that the closeness of the words has led to the meanings "bleeding" into one another.

Comment: Both words *effect* and *affect* can be either a verb or a noun, although *affect* (noun) is pronounced differently. And the fact that *affect* (verb) and *effect* (noun) seem like a noun-verb pair makes them completely confusing.

Comment: *effect* and *affect* are not a pair like the others, they are completely different words with coincidentally similar spellings.

Comment: @curiousdannii ... and in many dialects, identical pronunciations.

Answer (score 2):

They are known as ***Heterographs***, if they are spelled differently and have different meanings.

> Heterographs are words that sound the same, but are spelled differently and have different meanings. They are also known as homophonic heterographs.

See the below Venn Diagram(From [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Homograph_homophone_venn_diagram.png))

[image: Venn Diagram]

Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterograph)

Comment: _advice_ and _advise_ are pronounced differently. _licence_ and _license_ are pronounced the same. _effect_ and _affect_ may or may not be pronounced the same depending on the speaker. I would argue that within each pair they have the same meaning, even though the part of speech is different. This may not be a popular view, I don't know.

Comment: @CJDennis *effect* and *affect* don't have the same meaning at all; they're really just coincidentally similar. The question would be better if it asked about the noun and verb forms of both of those verbs separately.